# Only allow sub to run after another has been run VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a workbook that imports data from another file and then deletes any rows by finding a header string "Time". However, if the macro that deletes the rows is run again it will remove the header as there's a sub-header called "Time" as well.

OR is there a way to limit the characters Find searches for i.e. say my subheader is Real Time and my char limit is 4, find should only return "real" and therefore ignore that?

What I want to do is disable the Row Delete code unless there has been a new data import and the Row Delete hasn't already been run.

Some psuedo code below

```
If (DataImport has been run){
   If (rowDelete has been run since DataImport){
          return;
   }
   else{
   run rowDelete
   }
}
```

Excel VBA

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim pastestart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook 'Sheets("Data")
Set pastestart = [Data!A1]

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a data file")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "error"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

    For Each sheet In wb2.Sheets
        With sheet.UsedRange
            .Copy pastestart
            Set pastestart = pastestart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End With
    Next sheet
End If

    wb2.Close
End Sub

_____________________________________________________________________

Sub rowDelete()

    Dim FindRow As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    With Sheets("Data")
        Set FindRow = Cells.Find(What:="Time", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Range("A1", FindRow).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: You could read the number of rows (store it somewhere) and then check if the number of rows are different? if they are then run rowdelete else dont

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could include a cell on a worksheet which states whether an import has been made since the last row delete; include a line of code at the end of your `ImportData` procedure which updates this cell.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "Imported"
```

Then at the end of the `rowDelete` procedure you can update this cell to reflect that the rows have been deleted.

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "Rows deleted"`

Then within the `rowDelete` procedure you can check if the last procedure to be run was `rowDelete`. If it was, do not run the procedure.

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "Rows deleted" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

If the cell shows that the `ImportData` procedure was run last (because the cell shows "Imported") then the `rowDelete` procedure can run.

Comment: +1 I like this better than mine :) - but the cell you are using should be locked so is not manually altered..correct?

Comment: Thanks :). If others will be using the file, then I agree. Otherwise, I think we can trust @Gurdeep!

Comment: Thank you! This works, and is simple enough to explain to whoever wants to edit my sheets.

Answer (score 1):

How about using CustomDocumentProperties instead. Makes it more invisible:

```
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("Imported")
```

You can make this a yes/no property

Comment: Thanks, this is better, keeps my sheet nice and clean. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

YOu could use global variables to identify, will the below work for you?

Make sure you call InitiParams at the begining of the cycle

```
Dim Option Explicit
'Module Level Variables
Dim boolDataImportComplete as boolean
Dim boolRowDeleteRunComplete as boolean    

Sub InitParams()
   boolDataImportComplete = False
   boolRowDeleteRunComplete = False
End Sub

Sub ImportData()
    ''' Your Code here

    boolDataImportComplete  = True
End Sub

Sub RowDelete()
    ''' YOUR Code here
    boolRowDeleteRunComplete  = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will go with lturner's suggestion as there's less subs involved.